# Prandtl boundary layer equations for two-dimensional steady laminar flow of incompressible fluid over a semi-infinite plate are given by

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, general-relativity, mathematical-physics, mathematics

Prandtl boundary layer equations for two-dimensional steady laminar flow of incompressible fluid over a semi-infinite plate are given by

[image]jpg